# "Non-trivial element" in factor group terminology

Tags: group-theory, terminology

> Let $G$ be an abelian group. Let $T$ be the set of elements in $G$
>   with finite period. ($T$ is called the *torsion* subgroup of $G$.) 
>   Show that $T$ is a normal subgroup in $G$, and show that all non-trivial
>   elements  in $G/T$ have  infinite period.

In the context of this question, what is understood by "a non-trivial element of $G/T$"? I guess any element $xT \neq T$ ($x \in G$). Is this common terminology?

Comment: I think they just mean besides the identity element.

Comment: Yes, since $T$ is the identity element of $G/T$.

Comment: A *non-trivial* element in a group $G$ always denotes any element different from $e$. This is standard terminology. Here $G=G/T$ and $e=T$.

Comment: @Burde Okay. I only knew the terminology for non trivial subgroups to mean subgroups other than the subgroup consisting of just the identity element. Never came across the term trivial element (Lang's Undergraduate Algebra textbook).

Comment: A  subgroup is called *non-trivial* if it contains a non-trivial element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *trivial* element of a group is the identity. In a factor group (often called *quotient group*) $G/T$, the trivial element is the coset $T$. So yes, the non-trivial elements of $G/T$ are the cosets $xT$ such that $xT \neq T$.

Answer (score 1):

The detailed proof I developed here do confirm your interpretation of a non trivial element of the quotient group was correct: any coset differing from the unit element of the quotient i.e. $T$.

Suppose $G$ is an abelian group. We denote 0 the unit element and +
the group law . The set of elements of order $n>0$ is the set $T_n=\{x\in G\ |\ nx=0\}$ $nx$ stands here for $x+\ldots + x$ (addition iterated $n$ times). We set $T=\bigcup_n T_n$

#### T is a normal sub-group of G

$0 \in T$ since n0=0; Given $x$ and $y$ two elements of $T$ of order $n$ and $m$ respectively. From associativity and commutativity of + on G:
$nm(x+y) = n(mx) + m(ny) = 0+0 =0$,i.e. $x+y$ is of finite order $mn$,
which shows than $T$ is stable under addition. Let $i:x\mapsto -x$ the central  inversion of the group G. This is an inner (auto)morphism of G. Then For any element $x\in T$ of order $n$, $i(nx)=ni(x)= (-x) +\ldots + (-x) = n(-x) = -nx$. Then  $nx =0 \Rightarrow n(-x) =0$ which shows the stability of T under inversion. One now shows that $T$ is normal i.e. that $(\forall x\in G)\ (x)+T+(-x)=T$. Any element of the form  $x+t+(-x)$ $x \in G, t\in T$ is equal to $t$ by commutativity of the law + on G. We conclude that $T$ is a normal subgroup of G.

#### Quotient group G/T

We note $y+(-x)\equiv y-x$. We consider now $y-x\in T$ also noted $x\equiv y(T)$ as an equivalence relation on $G$. The quotient set $G/T$ is an
abelian group for the quotient law $[x]+[y]=[x+y]$ for any two classes equivalences (or cosets) of G/T $[x]$ and $[y]$ represented by
elements $x$ and $y$ of $G$. $[0]=T$ is acting as the unit element of the quotient group.

Suppose there is an element of $G/T$ of finite order, say a
non-trivial coset $x+T$ ($x\neq 0$) of order $n$. Then $n(x+T)=nx+nT=nx+T=T$ implies $nx\in T$, i.e. $nx$ of finite order, say $m>0$ such that $mnx=0$. But now $x$ has finite order whence belongs to $T$. $x+T=T$ which is
contradictory since $x+T$ is non-trivial.